# Entity framework code first - map class with List<> of another class to multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I'm evaluating EF4 and have a pretty basic question...I think, that I can't seem to find an answer for..

take the following example:

```
public class Question
{
  public string question {get;set;}
  public string answer {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Question> Questions {get; set;}
}
```

Then I have the following tables in the database

```
Person
(
 id,
 name
)

Question
(
 id,
 personId,
 question,
 answer,
)
```

Can I use the EF4 code first to map the Person class to the two tables, or do I ahve to restructure my POCO's first so the question class contains the id and personId - which is not something I would like to do.

Can I add something to the OnModelCreating to map the class as I need it to be mapped?

Thanks!

Comment: You mentioned `map the Person class to the two tables` and then later `to restructure my POCO's so the question class contains the id and personId`, which does not make sense, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't phrase this question right - I was wondering can I setup a mapping of the Person class to the two tables in the DB as they currently exist or do I have to refactor the question class to contain the extra properties to correspond to the question table in the database - See my own answer for what I have done to get this working for now (I restructured the classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's what I've done for now - but it requires me having to restructure my question class...

```
public class Question
{  
    public int Id {get;set;}   /* New */
    public int PersonId {get;set;}  /* New */
    public string question {get;set;}  
    public string answer {get; set;}

    public virtual Person PersonObj {get;set;}
}

public class Person
{  
    public string Id {get; set;}  
    public string Name {get; set;}  
    public List<Question> Questions {get; set;}
}
```

and added the following in the OnModelCreating event

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().
                    HasMany(d => d.Questions).
                    WithRequired(c => c.Person).
                    HasForeignKey(c => c.PersonId).
                    WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Not sure it's fully right...but seems to be working for now.

Comment: Actually I'm not really comfortable with the virtual properties...is there any way round them?

Comment: Marking the properties `virtual` ensures that they will be lazy-loaded.  See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx for examples.  Also, if you're satisfied with this solution, you should mark it as the answer.

Comment: Lazy loading is good - but why have that property at all? could I just have the PersonId and not a reference to the person object?