# Mapping Entities with Entity Framework 5 code first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-5, ddd-repositories

I have 2 entities, a Patient that has a collection of studies.

```
public class Patient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Study> Studies { get; set; }
}

public class Study
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map this object to 2 tables in the database "*Patients*" and "*Studies*".
What should be the **syntax** for doing this?
I am using "*EntityTypeConfiguration*".

```
class PatientEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        this.Property(p => p.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        //TODO: Map the studies!!!

        this.ToTable("Patients");
    }
}
```

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389265/entity-framework-code-first-map-class-with-list-of-another-class-to-multiple or http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't have to manually create the plural versions of the tables unless you are specifically turning this off with your own implementation of the [PluralizationService](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/12/02/pluralization.aspx)

I would update your model a bit:

```
public class Study
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    //Add the navigation for Patient
    public virtual Patient Patient {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your mapping would look like this. By making the properties virtual you allow for Lazy Loading:

```
class PatientEntityTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientEntityTypeConfiguration()
    {
       HasKey(p => p.Id);

       Property(p => p.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

       HasMany(p => p.Studies)
       .WithRequired(s => s.Patient)
       .HasForeignKey(s => s.PatientId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    }
}
```